# How to update the time when making a simple clock on assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

> Complete the clock-program, by writing the subroutines delay and time2string. Instructions to time2string: Register $a0 contains the address of an area in memory, suitably large for the output from time2string. The 16 least significant bits of register $a1 contains time-info, organized
> as four NBCD-coded digits of 4 bits each. All other bits in register $a1 can have any value and
> must be ignored.

This is what I have done so far, there is no problem in the other parts of the code since they are given. The only parts I wrote are hexasc, time2string, delay.

```
.macro  PUSH (%reg)   #  reg defines a parameter
    addi    $sp,$sp,-4    # reserve space for that data
    sw  %reg,0($sp)   # Stores  the register specified by %reg at the memory location pointed to by $sp. 
.end_macro

.macro  POP (%reg)
    lw  %reg,0($sp) #loads from memory to register %reg
    addi    $sp,$sp,4
.end_macro

    .data
    .align 2
mytime: .word 0x5957
timstr: .ascii "text more text lots of text\0"
    .text
main:
    # print timstr
    la  $a0,timstr
    li  $v0,4
    syscall
    nop
    # wait a little
    li  $a0,2
    jal delay
    nop
    # call tick
    la  $a0,mytime
    jal tick
    nop
    # call your function time2string
    la  $a0,timstr
    la  $t0,mytime
    lw  $a1,0($t0)
    jal time2string    #it calls on the funciton and return memory is saved
    nop
    # print a newline
    li  $a0,10
    li  $v0,11
    syscall
    nop
    # go back and do it all again
    j   main
    nop
# tick: update time pointed to by $a0
tick:   lw  $t0,0($a0)  # get time    loads data from the data memory and it access the from memory location from $a0
    addiu   $t0,$t0,1   # increase     unsigned addition
    andi    $t1,$t0,0xf # check lowest digit
    sltiu   $t2,$t1,0xa # if digit < a, okay      performs unsigned comparisson then t2 will either be 1 or 0
    bnez    $t2,tiend      # if not equal to 0, then jump to tiend
    nop
    addiu   $t0,$t0,0x6 # adjust lowest digit
    andi    $t1,$t0,0xf0    # check next digit
    sltiu   $t2,$t1,0x60    # if digit < 6, okay
    bnez    $t2,tiend
    nop
    addiu   $t0,$t0,0xa0    # adjust digit
    andi    $t1,$t0,0xf00   # check minute digit
    sltiu   $t2,$t1,0xa00   # if digit < a, okay
    bnez    $t2,tiend
    nop
    addiu   $t0,$t0,0x600   # adjust digit
    andi    $t1,$t0,0xf000  # check last digit
    sltiu   $t2,$t1,0x6000  # if digit < 6, okay
    bnez    $t2,tiend
    nop
    addiu   $t0,$t0,0xa000  # adjust last digit
tiend:  sw  $t0,0($a0)  # save updated result       sw= stores 4-byte word  0($a0): This part specifies the memory address where the contents of $t0 will be stored.
    jr  $ra     # return
    nop

  # you can write your code for subroutine "hexasc" below this line
  #
  
  
hexasc:

       andi  $v0, $a0, 15     #15 is 1111, so 

       slti  $t0, $v0, 10     #if t0 is less than 10, it sets it 1 otherwise 0

       beq   $t0, 1, low      #if t0 is equal to 1 then call the subroutine low

       beq   $t0, 0, high     #if t0 is 0 then call the subroutine high


low:
       addi $v0, $v0, 0x30    # 0x30 is 48 in base 16, add the input v0
       jr $ra                 #we jump back to main

high:
       addi $v0, $v0, 0x37    #0x37 = 55 in base 10, then we add the input v0
       jr $ra                #jump back to main
       
       
delay:
       jr $ra
       nop
       
    

       

time2string: 
            PUSH ($s0)
            PUSH ($s1)
            PUSH ($ra)

            add $s0, $a0, 0
            add $s1, $a1, 0
            
            addi $t1, $s1, 0xf000
            srl  $a1, $s1, 12 
            jal hexasc
            sb $v0, 0($s0)
            
            addi $t1, $s1, 0x0f00
            srl  $a1, $s1, 8 
            jal hexasc
            sb $v0, 1($s0)
            
            li $t0, 0x3A
            sb $t0, 2($s0)

            addi $t1, $s1, 0x00f0
            srl  $a1, $s1, 4
            jal hexasc
            sb $v0, 3($s0)
            
            addi $t1, $s1, 0xf000
            srl  $a1, $s1, 12 
            jal hexasc
            sb $v0, 4($s0)                          

###############################################################

        
###############################################################

            li  $t1, 0x00           
            sb  $t1, 5($s0)
########################################################
            POP ($ra)
        POP ($s1)
        POP ($s0)   
        jr   $ra
```

Comment: What time do you want to update? This is homework, it's better if you ask your professor during office hours.

Comment: It is my understanding that the subroutine "tick" updates the time whilst time2string masks, fix the digits etc so it looks like 00:00. Now tick is perfectly fine since it is not my code, but something about time2string is not giving me the desired outcome. It keeps priniting the same time. Too few office hours and too many people that need help.

Answer (score 2):

- Your instructor's code is consistently using `nop` after any call, `jal ...` or return `jr $ra`, and thus so should you, since it seems possible that Delayed Branching is set as enabled/on for your simulator situation.  So, insert `nop`s wherever you do jumps or branches — note that this includes `beq` and `bne`.  (If delayed branches are being used, and you forget to use a `nop` somewhere, it can be very confusing as to what's happening or going wrong.)
- You're using `addi` to extract digits where you wanted to used `andi`, so just a typo in the opcode (but you should be able to observe that these aren't working as you intend, and suggests you're not single step debugging).
- Though this may work the control flow is excessive and inefficient, though this is just a nit:

  ```
   beq   $t0, 1, low      #if t0 is equal to 1 then call the subroutine low
   beq   $t0, 0, high     #if t0 is 0 then call the subroutine high
  ```

  You only need one conditional branch to test a condition, no need to use another branch to test the exact opposite condition.  Can you come up with the one branch that will work there?  Don't forget to use `nop` after branches.

  Also, should test against 0 instead of 1 whenever possible, and, 0 as $0 — `beq $t0, 1, low` would be better as `bne $t0, $0, low` (has same meaning as we know here the value in $t0 has to be either 0 or 1), as would your `beq $t0, 0, high` as `beq $t0, $0, high`.

With those changes you should get much closer to the right clock.  However, there are additional bugs, and you should learn to single step in the debugger to observe each line of code execute and see if it's results are as intended.  Debugging assembly is mostly the same as debugging other code: single step to run each line one at a time and observe the effects that line had on the state of the program, comparing with what you think that line should do or should have done.